# Magento site down due to mysql error General error: 1030 Got error -1 from storage engine

Tags: mysql, magento

I even deleted all records from log_visitor table, still getting the same issue. Following is the stack I am getting.
    SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1030 Got error -1 from storage engine

```
#0 /home/site/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/site/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/site/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/site/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):     Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#4 /home/site/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#5 /home/site/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#6 /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(453): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('log_visitor', Array)
#7 /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#8 /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php(167): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#9 /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Log_Model_Visitor->initByRequest(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#10 /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor), 'initByRequest', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /home/site/public_html/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#12 /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(528): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#13 /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php(64): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#14 /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(408): Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->preDispatch()
#15 /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#16 /home/site/public_html/app/code/local/SM/Vendors/Controller/Router/Vendor.php(76): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#17 /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): SM_Vendors_Controller_Router_Vendor->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#18 /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#19 /home/site/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#20 /home/site/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#21 {main}

Fatal error: Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0
```

This is a live site, I need make it live as soon as possible. Please help.

Comment: Did you try restarting the server?

Comment: check if the table is broken with "CHECK TABLE" and "repair table". http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/check-table.html

Comment: and if this table is corrupt, take your time and run mysqlcheck on all tables - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html - there might be more broken tables in the database.

Comment: I tried repair, but got a response that engine dosnt support repair.

Comment: can you post the output of "check table" first?

Comment: assuming from the error message that Magento uses Innodb and not myisam tables this blog post  could be helpful for you http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/07/04/recovering-innodb-table-corruption/

Comment: can you connect to the database via command line and insert something into the table? Does this work?

Comment: Do you have any support from your hosting company? Your database is broken and will need some TLC. Your going to need to run check table on all tables that are called. Try clearing the magento cache from var as well as they may be corrupted. Try deleting all data from log_* and then running check table.

Comment: What engine set for that specific table.As Innodb engine should be set for all tables excluding table that uses fulltext search e.g `catalogsearch_fulltext`

Comment: How did this end, @user1105351 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a general error that happens when InnoDB cannot write to its data files.

I've seen reports of this when the disk is full, or if permissions on the files changed so you can't write to them.

Another report was when someone enabled `innodb_force_recovery` to a value greater than 0, not realizing that in recovery modes >0, InnoDB is effectively read-only.

I hope this helps.

Comment: As soon as I read this I smacked myself in the face...realising that I enabled the force recovery option earlier because of a damaged table. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try deleting the folders var/cache and var/session it works for me