# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1030 Got error 28 from storage engine in magento site

Tags: sql, magento, amazon-web-services

We are facing the following problem at GMT 5 pm from last 2 days.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1030 Got error 28 from storage engine.

We have a 100 gb disk space with server on amazon web service [VPS]. There is a Magento site running with 20 gb data. At night when we check the site, we got following error:

[image]

When we checked the disk space, it was 95% full. Then when we restarted MySQL, it was back to normal 20 gb. Why did the disk space suddenly increas from 20 gb to 95 gb overnight?

Comment: Presumably you had some query running that used lots of temporary or log space.

Comment: is query will affect that much ?

Comment: i saw this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002461/magento-site-down-due-to-mysql-error-general-error-1030-got-error-1-from-stora, but i  dont know how to enable this : innodb_force_recovery to 0

Comment: Please check server log as well as  Magento log, exception log and error reports also

Comment: i deleted all log files yesterday morning, but  yesterday night it appeared.

Comment: please help me by seeing this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002461/magento-site-down-due-to-mysql-error-general-error-1030-got-error-1-from-stora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I cleared the cache and session folders then deleted some unwanted files. I turned off scheduled back up. Next day I checked and the not problem was gone. Everything is fine now.